# Loop through list of dictionaries simlutaneously

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists of dictionaries that look like:

```
a=[{"Name":"JD","Lat":12.1231,"Long":10.123},{"Name":"WQ","Lat":-1.21313,"Long":7.31}]  
b=[{"Name":"JD","Time":datetime.datetime(1,2,3)},{"Name":"WQ","Time":datetime.datetime(4,5,6)}]
```

I want to loop through the two simultaneously:

```
for i,j in a,b:
      Do Something
```

I get

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

Also for

```
for i,j in zip(a,b):  
      Do Something
```

I do not get any output at all.
zip(a,b) is an empty list.
How should I go about this?

Comment: What python version do you use?

Comment: What are you actually doing in the "Do Something" section? It would help if you gave us a [mcve] that illustrates your problem. Also, what version of Python are you using? In Python 2, `zip` returns a list of tuples, in Python 3 it returns an iterator.

Comment: Python 2.7 and @Telac a and b are lists of dicts iteritems is not an option!

Comment: can you post the full traceback of the error ? I would bet that culprit is in the Do something part ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip)

```
for i,j in zip(a,b):
```

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't give any output at all!

Comment: @glitterati could you add that try to your question please?

Comment: If you do not output something with e.g. print then of course it does not generate any output. I just tested it and it works. But you have some errors in your array literal because the call to datetime() requires some parameters like year, month and day. Test it e.g. with a = [1,2,3,4] and b = [5,6,7,8] and you will see that it works

Comment: @glitterati I can confirm that. It even works in python 2.7

Comment: It doesn't work, I get the error above!

Comment: I have many more dicts in each of the lists and all are of the same format!

Comment: Then you have to add more information as we cannot help you when it works for me and for others with your specified sample data. Did you try it with the simple int lists [1,2,...]? If yes and it works then paste a small but complete and valid (no 'Do something') python example which produces your error - otherwise everyone is just guessing.